# Verilog, generic adder tree

Tags: verilog

So, I'm trying to write an adder tree in verilog. The generic part of it is that it has a configurable number of elements to add and a configurable word size. However, I'm encountering problem after problem and I'm starting to question that this is the right way to solve my problem. (I will be using it in a larger project.) It is definately possible to just hard code the adder tree, alhough that will take alot of text.

So, I though I'd check with you stack overflowers on what you think about it. Is this "the way to do it"? I'm open for suggestions on different approaches too.

I can also mention that I'm quite new to verilog.

In case anyone is interested, here's my current non-working code: (I'm not expecting you to solve the problems; I'm just showing it for convenience.)

```
module adderTree(
    input clk,
    input [`WORDSIZE * `BANKSIZE - 1 : 0] terms_flat,
    output [`WORDSIZE - 1 : 0] sum
);

genvar i, j;

reg [`WORDSIZE - 1 : 0] pipeline [2 * `BANKSIZE - 1 : 0];   // Pipeline array
reg clkPl = 0;                                              // Pipeline clock

assign sum = pipeline[0];

// Pack flat terms
generate
    for (i = `BANKSIZE; i < 2 * `BANKSIZE; i = i + 1) begin
        always @ (posedge clk) begin
            pipeline[i] <= terms_flat[i * `WORDSIZE +: `WORDSIZE];
            clkPl = 1;
        end
    end
endgenerate

// Add terms logarithmically
generate
    for (i = 0; i < $clog2(`BANKSIZE); i = i + 1) begin
        for (j = 0; j < 2 ** i; j = j + 1) begin
            always @ (posedge clkPl) begin
                pipeline[i * (2 ** i) + j] <= pipeline[i * 2 * (2 ** i) + 2 * j] + pipeline[i * 2 * (2 ** i) + 2 * j + 1];
            end
        end
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Comment: Since you got no specific questions, then maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a batter place for this?

Comment: Well, that's possible. But doesn't this ask the specific question of how to design an adder tree?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate what 'problem after problem' you are having? There's probably lots of different equally valid ways to write an adder tree.

Comment: Difficulties: array inputs must be flat; that is I every array element is only 1 bit wide. This makes the module hard to use with other modules and currently I'm not getting my other module to work with it, so I can't really test it and se if it does what I want. It took me a lot of time to write those `for` loops as I initially wanted several arrays generated within the `for` loop, but that doesn't seem to be allowed, so I created one large array instead and indexed it in a complex way. All of this makes me speculate that I'm either doing it wrong or that a generic AT isn't really feasable.

Comment: Unfortunately verilog is pretty limited when it comes to implementing very generic modules like this, it's not nearly as flexible as you'd expect coming from other programming languages. There's a lot of rules around arrays that prevent you using them in very creative ways. This is just my opinion so it's not canon, but IMHO (as an semi-experienced verilog design engineer) I would not try to write a module like this in pure verilog, but rather I would use a text parsing language (something like verilog-perl) that takes your input parameters and uses it to print out parameterized .v files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few comments you might find useful:

### CLOCKING

It is generally good to have as few clocks as possible in your design (preferably just one).

In this particular case it appears you are trying generating a new clock **clkPl**, but this does not work because it will never return to 0.  (The "reg clkPl=0;" will reset it to 0 at time 0, then it is set permanently to 1 in "clkPl = 1;".)

You can fix this by simply replacing

```
always @ (posedge clkPl)
```

with

```
always @ (posedge clk)
```

### ASSIGNMENTS

It is good form to only use blocking assignments in combinatorial blocks, and non-blocking in clocked blocks.  You are mixing both blocking and non-blocking assignments in your "Pack flat terms" section.

As you don't need **clkPl** you can simply delete the line with the blocking assignment ("clkPl = 1;")

### TREE STRUCTURE

Your double for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < $clog2(`BANKSIZE); i = i + 1) begin
    for (j = 0; j < 2 ** i; j = j + 1) begin
        always @ (posedge clkPl) begin
            pipeline[i * (2 ** i) + j] <= pipeline[i * 2 * (2 ** i) + 2 * j] + pipeline[i * 2 * (2 ** i) + 2 * j + 1];
        end
    end
end
```

looks like it will access incorrect elements.

e.g. for BANKSIZE = 2**8, **i** will count up to 7, at which point "pipeline[i * (2 ** i) + j]"="pipeline[7*2**7+j]"="pipeline[896+j] which will be out of bounds for the array. (The array has 2*BANKSIZE=512 elements in it.)

I think you actually want this structure:

```
assign sum = pipeline[1];
for (i = 1; i < `BANKSIZE; i = i + 1) begin
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        pipeline[i] <= pipeline[i*2] + pipeline[i*2 + 1];
        end
    end
```

### LOWER LATENCY

Note that most verilog tools are very good at synthesising adds of multiple elements so you may want to consider combining more terms at each level of the hierarchy.

(Adding more terms costs less than someone might expect because the tools can use optimisations such as [carry save adders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-save_adder) to reduce the gate delay.)

Comment: Thank you! That clears up a lot of things. Yeah, I meant to clear the clock in the second always block. The reason I had 2 clocks in the first place is that I was worried the different always blocks would access `pipeline` simultaneously. Is there not a problem with this?

Comment: `always @(posedge clk)` implies a flip flop, if the generate blasts this to only be 1 unique bit then think of it as one flip flop for pipeline_1 and another called pipeline_2, you are free to assign these in different `always` processes, as long as only 1 sets, any number can read.